# Dirac's theorem question

Tags: graph-theory

Give an example to show that the condition $\deg(v) \geq n/2$ in the statement of Dirac's theorem cannot be replaced by $\deg(v) \geq (n-1)/2$

The textbook gives the solution:
The complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2 - 1, n/2 + 1}$ if $n$ is even, and $K_{(n-1)/2, (n+1)/2}$ if $n$ is odd.

If anyone can explain this more thoroughly it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete bipartite graph $K_{(n-1)/2, ~ (n+1)/2}$ has $(n-1)/2 + (n+1)/2 = n$ vertices.

Each vertex has degree greater than or equal to $(n-1)/2$ but this graph does not contain any Hamiltonian cycles, so the conclusion of Dirac's theorem does not hold.

You may wish to consider, for example, $K_{1,2}$ or $K_{2,3}$.

Comment: I don't think this reasoning applies to the case when $n$ is even: in $K_{n/2-1, n/2+1}$ each vertex has degree either $n/2-1$ or $n/2+1$. However, $n/2-1 = (n-2)/2<(n-1)/2$. So there are in fact $n/2+1$ vertices with degrees less than $(n-1)/2$. For example, $n=4$ gives $K_{2-1, 2+1} = K_{1,3}$ which has $3$ vertices of degree $1$.